# Python graph ""*

Tags: python, graph

Как! можно отрисовать ( Эллипс )? 
Знаю что можно использовать более годные библеотеки но мне нужно именно на graph

Answer (score 1):

Что значит Sos в названии темы? Если хотите, чтобы Ваши вопросы воспринимали серьёзно, постарайтесь написать нормальное название темы и сформулировать вопрос.
Полукруг и эллипс - это две разные фигуры.
Обе можно отрисовать с помощью библиотеки matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Wedge
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ellipse = Ellipse((0.25,0.25), 0.2, 0.4)
semicircle = Wedge((0.75,0.75), 0.2, 90, 270)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
ax.add_patch(semicircle)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
fig.show()
```